# What is the origin of the literal type charcter 'R' for the datatype Double in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

In the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x99xtshc.aspx) is states:

> **Type Characters.** Appending the literal type character **R** to a literal forces it to the **Double** data type. For example, if an integer value is followed by **R**, the value is changed to a **Double**.

is this a silly question but why R?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s9cz43ek.aspx

Comment: Since `D` is taken with Decimal, perhaps they went with `R` for [Real](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_number).  Just speculation though...

Comment: @Dandy yeah, but why R? does that link explain, couldn't see it!

Comment: @JamesThorpe , so it was a silly question.. :| cheers,Ears.

Answer (score 3):

(I assume) It is because `D` was already used for `Decimal` (because it came first alphabetically), so they used `R` to indicate a [Real Number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_number)